# Haskell mapM_ to other format

Tags: haskell, io

Although I have the feeling I am progressing in Haskell I am still not a hundred percent comfortable with contexts. Take the code here:

```
extractData :: IO ()
extractData = do
  id <- getLine
  let userToolIDSelect = (read id) :: Int
  connection <- open "tools.db"
  resp <- query connection "SELECT * FROM tools WHERE toolID = (?);"
    (Only userToolIDSelect) :: IO [Tool]
  mapM_ print resp
```

Works fine, but how I can use `mapM_` to generate something I can work with? I can only get it to print to the console, but I would like to have eg. a list back so I can write it to a  file and import it in another file for processing... 
The number of possibilities and libraries in Haskell dazzles me a bit and makes me loose focus sometimes. Think this is that time again..

Comment: This is too vague. You want to replace `mapM_` with "something I can work with", which could be anything at all. You should clarify your goal. Note that you already have a list: `resp`. You can work with that without `mapM_`, if you want. E.g. you can write `resp` to a file.

Comment: If you need to work with mutable structure, e.g. [STArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html#t:STArray), you may find that the functions like mapM_, forM_ or etc are useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just pass a function you want instead of `print`. Either using lambda, for simple things:

```
mapM_ (\tool -> ...) resp
```

or as separate IO action:

```
doSomethingWithTool :: Tool -> IO ()
doSomethingWithTool tool = do
  ...
  return ()
```

and then

```
mapM_ doSomethingWithTool resp
```

Comment: @chi: it is vague. Sorry. [at]Arrowd understood. That was the answer I was looking for. Was trying to get it out of the Monad, but then realized that that is impossible.